# Shemiras einayim & non-essential trips

Tags: halacha, sexuality, kedusha-holiness, shemirat-eynayim

What heterim are there for people to go on non-essential trips that will inevitably result in breaches of shemiras einayim and machshava. I heard on a recent Headlines podcast that Reb Moshe Feinstein said that one shouldn't just go on a walk along the boardwalk at a beach.

What are the gedarim - how far does one take this. Would one be able to go visit a museum in the city as a recreational outlet?

Does halacha take into account how predisposed one is to having mikreh layla - i.e. if it is very common does this mean one should avoid going out unless strictly necessary?

Comment: "gedarim" it seems highly unlikely there are fixed gedarim.

Comment: @Alex *When you edit, would you please capitalize Hebrew words - it will make them stand out clearly pointing that that's a term.*

Comment: Al Berko, @Alex, comments are not meant for extended discussion, so this discussion has been continued to [chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46070987#46070987).